# ACME certificates timeout with traefik

Tags: docker, dns, traefik

#### Hello!

I am having issues finding out the reason why I am getting this error. Tried googling it.
It seems to be an issue with dns lookup from the container.

#### Error in traefik log:

```
time="2020-01-30T12:12:12+01:00" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"traefik.xyz.se\": cannot get ACME client get directory at 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory': Get https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory: dial tcp: lookup acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:54773->127.0.0.11:53: i/o timeout" providerName=cloudflare.acme routerName=traefik-secure@docker rule="Host(`traefik.xyz.se`)"
time="2020-01-30T12:12:32+01:00" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"hivemq.xyz.se\": cannot get ACME client get directory at 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory': Get https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory: dial tcp: lookup acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:53671->127.0.0.11:53: i/o timeout" rule="Host(`hivemq.xyz.se`)" providerName=cloudflare.acme routerName=hivemq-secure@docker
```

#### Unable to lookup google from within traefik container. Don't know if this is working as intended?

```
/o/a/traefik> docker exec -it traefik /bin/sh
/ # nslookup google.se
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

nslookup: can't resolve 'google.se': Try again
/ #
```

#### Traefik docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.1
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    environment:
      - CF_API_EMAIL=redacted
      - CF_API_KEY=redacted
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - ./data/acme.json:/acme.json
      - ./data/config.yml:/config.yml:ro
    labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.xyz.se`)"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=redacted"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`traefik.xyz.se`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=cloudflare"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].main=xyz.se"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].sans=*.xyz.se"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"    
networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

#### data/traefik.yml:

```
api:
  dashboard: true
  debug: true

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    filename: /config.yml

certificatesResolvers:
  cloudflare:
    acme:
      email: redacted
      storage: acme.json
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: cloudflare
        delayBeforeCheck: 0
        resolvers:
          - "1.1.1.1:53"
          - "8.8.8.8:53"
```

#### Service example (hivemq) docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  hivemq:
    image: hivemq/hivemq4
    container_name: hivemq
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    ports:
      - 1883:1883
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.hivemq.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.hivemq.rule=Host(`hivemq.xyz.se`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.hivemq.middlewares=https-redirect@file"
      - "traefik.http.routers.hivemq-secure.middlewares=secured@file"
      - "traefik.http.routers.hivemq-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.hivemq-secure.rule=Host(`hivemq.xyz.se`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.hivemq-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.hivemq-secure.service=hivemq"
      - "traefik.http.services.hivemq.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
    networks:
      - internal
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false
```

I have also tried reinstalling docker-ce, didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and it was due to a bug of Docker: all my containers had lost their connection to the internet but they were all already removed for maintenance puprose so I couldn't see it.

In the logs, `cannot get ACME client get directory` means that Traefik cannot connect to Let's Encrypt url.

I fixed it by:

- Removing Traefik stack
- Pruning networks so traefik-public was removed
- Restarting Docker service

If it's not enough, you can try these:

- Try to restart the Docker Engine, which will reset any iptables rules (assuming you are using Docker on Linux)
- Try to restart your whole machine
- Try to disable (temporary) the firewall of your machine to verify that it fixes the issue

As mentioned here: https://community.containo.us/t/cannot-create-renew-acme-certificate-cannot-get-acme-client-get-directory/2469/2

I gave a rapid look around concerning Docker bugs about loosing connection and seems to be a mess, for years: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15172

Answer (score 0):

Not a docker specialist but I had a similar issue and fixed it by activating ipv6 on docker daemon :

```
% grep ipv6 /etc/docker/daemon.json
    "ipv6": true`
```

You need to reload docker daemon then

```
% sudo systemctl reload docker
```