# Traefik Redirect Domain to Subdomain

Tags: lets-encrypt, traefik, http-redirect

I want to permanently redirect all requests to `example.com` and `www.example.com` to `blog.example.com` in a TLS environment.

My current config:

*traefik.toml*:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint]
      to = "websecure"
      scheme = "https"

  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"

[providers.docker]
  exposedbydefault = false
  watch = true
  network = "web"
[providers.file]
  filename = "traefik_dynamic.toml"

[certificatesResolvers.lets-encrypt.acme]
  email = "mymail@example.com"
  storage = "/letsencrypt/acme.json"
  [certificatesResolvers.lets-encrypt.acme.dnsChallenge]
    provider = "myprovider"
```

*traefik_dynamic.toml*:

```
[http.middlewares] 
  [http.middlewares.goToBlog.redirectregex] 
    regex = "^https://(.*)example.com/(.*)" 
    replacement = "https://blog.example.com/$${2}"
    permanent = true
 
[http.routers] 
  [http.routers.gotoblog] 
    rule = "Host(`example.com`) || Host(`www.example.com`)" 
    entrypoints = ["websecure"] 
    middlewares = ["goToBlog"] 
    service = "noop@internal" 
    [http.routers.gotoblog.tls] 
      certResolver = "lets-encrypt"
```

When I try to access `example.com` it gives my an SSL Protocol Error. All my other endpoints including `blog.example.com` are working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, obviously it had nothing to do with my redirect configuration. Seemed like a hickup in traefik / docker, similar to [ACME certificates timeout with traefik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60029532/acme-certificates-timeout-with-traefik). Just waited one day and everything worked as expected. Just two minor updates to correct the redirect configuration. Maybe there's a more elegant solution.

*traefik_dynamic.toml*:

```
[http.middlewares] 
  [http.middlewares.goToBlog.redirectregex] 
    regex = "^https://(.*)example.com/(.*)" 
    replacement = "https://blog.example.com/${2}"         # no double $$
    permanent = true
 
[http.routers] 
  [http.routers.gotoblog] 
    rule = "Host(`example.com`, `www.example.com`)"       # just an array of domains is fine, too
    entrypoints = ["websecure"] 
    middlewares = ["goToBlog"] 
    service = "noop@internal" 
    [http.routers.gotoblog.tls] 
      certResolver = "lets-encrypt"
```