# Redirect from non-www to www with Traefik 2

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I would like to redirect from non-www to www.

**What I would like to do:**

Type in the browser:

https://domainname.com

obtain:

https://www.domainname.com

**What I write:**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  traefik:
    build: ./traefik
    image: image-traefik-eb:v.1.0
    container_name: container-traefik-eb
    command:
      - --log.level=INFO
      - --log.filePath=/data-log/traefik.log
      - --log.format=json
      - --accesslog=true
      - --api.insecure
      - --api.dashboard
      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls=true
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.certresolver=leresolver
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.tlsChallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.email=#########@gmail.com
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.middlewares.redirect-non-www-to-www.redirectregex.permanent=true
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.middlewares.redirect-non-www-to-www.redirectregex.regex="^https?://(?:www\\.)?(.+)"
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.middlewares.redirect-non-www-to-www.redirectregex.replacement="https://www.${1}"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./volumes/data-letsencrypt/:/letsencrypt
      - ./volumes/data-log/:/data-log/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - eb
      - traefik-network
      
  php:
    build: ./php-apache
    image: image-php-apache-eb:v.1.0
    labels:
      traefik.enable: 'true'
      traefik.http.services.php.loadbalancer.server.port: 80
      traefik.http.services.php.loadbalancer.server.scheme: http
      traefik.http.routers.php.rule: Host(`www.#########.ml`,`#########.ml`)
      traefik.http.routers.php.middlewares: redirect-non-www-to-www
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/data-php:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    networks:
      - eb

networks:
  eb:
    internal: true
  traefik-network:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1-apache
EXPOSE 80
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM traefik:v2.8.0
```

Source from which I got the code:

https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-redirect-from-non-www-to-www-with-traefik-659cb7197449

**What I get:**

```
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "command" option in service "traefik": "--entrypoints.websecure.http.middlewares.redirect-non-www-to-www.redirectregex.replacement="https://www.${1}""
ubuntu-22-04-lts@webserver:~/www.domainname.com$
```

**A few steps forward:**

*With this new configuration:*

A) I reach the dashboard in secure mode and on a valid certificate;

B) I reach the PHP service;

C) Redirect http to https and non-www to www;

*With this new configuration:*

D) I don't get a valid certificate for index.php (I get a certificate only for the dashboard)

E) I get a lot of error warnings on the nameserver.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  traefik:
    build: ./traefik
    image: image-traefik-eb:v.1.0
    container_name: container-traefik-eb
    command:
      - --log.level=INFO
      - --log.filePath=/data-log/traefik.log
      - --log.format=json
      - --accesslog=true
      - --api.insecure=false
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls=true
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.certresolver=leresolver
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.tlsChallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.email=domain-name@gmail.com
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json
    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule: Host(`www.traefik.domain-name.ga`)
      traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service: api@internal
      traefik.http.routers.dashboard.middlewares: auth
      traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users: user:***********************
      traefik.http.routers.unmatchedwww.rule: HostRegexp(`{name:^www\..*}`) 
      traefik.http.routers.unmatchedwww.service: noop@internal
      traefik.http.routers.unmatchedwww.priority: 2
      traefik.http.routers.matchlast.rule: PathPrefix(`/`)
      traefik.http.routers.matchlast.priority: 1
      traefik.http.routers.matchlast.middlewares: addwww
      traefik.http.middlewares.addwww.redirectregex.regex: ^https://(?:www\.)?(.*)
      traefik.http.middlewares.addwww.redirectregex.replacement: https://www.$${1}
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./volumes/data-letsencrypt/:/letsencrypt
      - ./volumes/data-log/:/data-log/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - eb
      - traefik-network
      
  php:
    build: ./php-apache
    image: image-php-apache-eb:v.1.0
    labels:
      traefik.enable: 'true'
      traefik.http.services.php.loadbalancer.server.port: 80
      traefik.http.services.php.loadbalancer.server.scheme: http
      traefik.http.routers.php.rule: Host(`www.domain-name.ga`)
      traefik.http.routers.php.tls.domains[0].main: domain-name.ga
      traefik.http.routers.php.tls.domains[0].sans: www.domain-name.ga
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/data-php:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    networks:
      - eb

networks:
  eb:
    internal: true
  traefik-network:
```

```
FROM traefik:v2.8.0
```

```
FROM php:8.1-apache
EXPOSE 80
```

**A few steps forward:**

With these codes I improve the situation:

```
traefik.http.routers.php.tls.certresolver: leresolver
Host(`www.traefik.domain-name.ga`,`traefik.domain-name.ga`)
```

but i have problems with these links:

```
'https://traefik.domain-name.ga/'
'http://traefik.domain-name.ga/'
```

Comment: At PHP service you have "traefik.http.routers.training2.middlewares: redirect-non-www-to-www@ file". That @ file from the post is there because his traefik's redirect configuration is part of the static file. So you need to remove @ file there for sure. Try to use it without @ file and see what the results are.

Comment: labels:
      traefik.enable: 'true'
      traefik.http.routers.training.rule: Host(`www.***.ml`)
      traefik.http.routers.training.middlewares: redirect-non-www-to-www

Comment: *** System restart required ***
Last login: Mon Jul 25 18:41:13 2022 from °°°°°
ubuntu-22-04-lts@webserver:~$ cd /home/ubuntu-22-04-lts/www.***.ml
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "command" option in service "traefik": "--entrypoints.websecure.http.middlewares.redirect-non-www-to-www.redirectregex.r                      eplacement="https://www.${1}""
ubuntu-22-04-lts@webserver:~/www.***.ml$

Comment: I also tried this code:

Comment: labels:
      traefik.enable: 'true'
      traefik.http.routers.training.rule: Host(`www.########.ml`,`########.ml`)
      traefik.http.middlewares.test-redirectregex.redirectregex.regex: ^http://########.ml/(.*)
      traefik.http.middlewares.test-redirectregex.redirectregex.replacement: http://www.########.ml/$${1}

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: @matic1123 , do you have any other suggestions for me?

Comment: And maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66400248/traefik-redirect-domain-to-subdomain to help you with the rule (it claims it should not have double $$ and such.

His/Hers configuration works, even tho it redirects to different domain, but it could be beneficial to you :)

Comment: @matic1123, I put all the configuration, can you watch now?

Comment: Sorry, was not near pc for the whole weekend (fri-mon). I'll test the config I have now and write an answer.

Comment: I have updated the post. It remains to understand how to obtain the certificates.

Comment: I have updated the code but there are still some problems with the Traefik dashboard. Is it possible that the case I am reporting is a bug? Where are Traefik bugs reported?

Answer (score 3):

I have taken your config and removed HTTPS configuration (so I tested with only HTTP, so no additional layers of complexity, just testing plain HTTP and redirect logic). You will need to adjust and add HTTPS on your own since we are not using any HTTPS with Traeifk so I can't really help you with that. But nonetheless:

About your redirect logic, I had to move

```
traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-non-www-to-www.redirectregex
```

logic to the Labels section of the depending service instead of the traefik configuration to make it work. I created a custom domain called 'my-custom-domain.org' and I edited my hosts' file, to point it to my local dev environment.

In the end i came down to the working configuration:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.8.1
    container_name: container-traefik-eb
    command:
      - --log.level=INFO
      - --log.format=json
      - --accesslog=true
      - --api.insecure
      - --api.dashboard
      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - eb
  
  php:
    image: nginx:latest
    labels:
      traefik.enable: 'true'
      traefik.http.services.php.loadbalancer.server.port: 80
      #traefik.http.services.php.loadbalancer.server.scheme: http
      traefik.http.routers.php.rule: Host(`www.my-custom-domain.org`,`my-custom-domain.org`)
      traefik.http.routers.php.service: php
      traefik.http.routers.php.entrypoints: web
      traefik.http.routers.php.middlewares: redirect-non-www-to-www
      traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-non-www-to-www.redirectregex.permanent: true
      traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-non-www-to-www.redirectregex.regex: "^http://my-custom-domain.org/(.*)"
      traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-non-www-to-www.redirectregex.replacement: "http://www.my-custom-domain.org/$${1}"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    networks:
      - eb

networks:
  eb:
    external: true
```

I have tested this configuration in incognito mode and it works as intended for all http://my-custom-domain.org -> http://www.my-custom-domain.org redirects.

I hope you find it useful and are successful with HTTPS additions, or that any other member which works with Traefik here will be able to help you with that issue.

Comment: Looks like someone beat me to it :)

But I would approach it the same way tbh.

Comment: One of the main reasons I use Traefik is to get Let's Encrypt certificates in an easy way. A website without https in 2022 no longer makes sense to exist. However, thank you very much for your efforts.

Comment: I added my new code, 99% working. Could you suggest me how to complete it 100%?